# Grouping records together using multiple record types in CsvHelper

Tags: c#, .net-core, csvhelper

I have a large log file containing different record types that I want to parse. It looks something like this:

```
$L,8,PO
$L,8,SF
$P,8,P,0,102,0,19:08:34.463
$P,9,P,0,110,0,19:08:34.460
$P,8,P,0,105,0,19:08:34.407
$L,8,SF
$P,9,A,0,139,0,19:08:34.374
$P,15,P,0,103,0,19:08:34.532
$P,8,P,0,73,0,19:08:34.436
$L,8,SF
$L,8,PI
```

I'm currently using CsvHelper and followed [this example](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-multiple-record-types) of how to read multiple record types using a switch statement. I'm a bit stuck however, as I want to group the $P records depending on values contained in the $L records and then write the output to separate CSV files.

For example, the first and last $L records both contain an 8 in the second field, plus PO/PI messages (this would be the start/end of my file for all $P records containing 8 in the second field). The file output for 8.csv would look like this:

```
$P,8,P,0,102,0,19:08:34.463
$P,8,P,0,105,0,19:08:34.407
$P,8,P,0,73,0,19:08:34.436
```

In addition to grouping them together this way, I would like to prepend a number ahead of the $P record depending on the $L messages which contain SF and the number 8. There are 3 SF messages above containing SF and 8, so the final file would look something like this:

```
1,$P,8,P,0,102,0,19:08:34.463
1,$P,8,P,0,105,0,19:08:34.407
2,$P,8,P,0,73,0,19:08:34.436
```

What's the best way to accomplish this? Currently I'm adding all $P messages that contain the same ID number to a dictionary with key value pair of : List<$P Record>, and I'm not quite sure how to make the $P record groupings depend on the values of the other record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.  It is easier to add lines to a record and then group the records.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication184
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count = 0;
            string line = "";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            List<Record> records = new List<Record>();
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                int startComment = line.IndexOf("//");
                if (startComment >= 0)
                {
                    line = line.Substring(0, startComment);
                }
                line = line.Trim();
                string[] splitArray = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToArray();
                Record newRecord = new Record();
                newRecord.car = int.Parse(splitArray[1]);
                newRecord.type = (Record.RECORD_TYPE)Enum.Parse(typeof(Record.RECORD_TYPE), splitArray[2]);
                records.Add(newRecord);

                switch (splitArray[0])
                {
                    case "$P":
                        newRecord.message = line;
                        break;
                }
            }

            var cars = records.GroupBy(x => x.car);

            foreach (var car in cars)
            {
                int lap = 0;
                int stint = 0;

                foreach (Record record in car)
                {
                    record.lap = lap;
                    record.stint = stint;
                    switch (record.type)
                    {
                        case Record.RECORD_TYPE.SF:
                            record.lap = ++lap;
                            break;
                        case Record.RECORD_TYPE.P:
                            string output = string.Join(",", new string[] { record.stint.ToString(), record.lap.ToString(), record.message });
                            Console.WriteLine(output);
                            break;
                        case Record.RECORD_TYPE.PO :
                            record.stint = ++stint;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
    public class Record
    {
        public enum RECORD_TYPE
        {
            PO,
            SF,
            P,
            PI,
            A
        }
        public RECORD_TYPE type { get; set; }
        public int stint { get; set; }
        public int lap { get; set; }
        public int car { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to increment the count each time an $L is reached without checking if the $L contains the same number as $P (or whether or not it is an SF, PO, or PI type). I assume I need to add checks for these and then act accordingly?

Comment: I don't think so.  You have too little info for me to deternine exactly what you need.  I've been parsing data like this for over 40 years and used my best judgement to come up with code above.

Comment: The $P messages are telemetry data from various cars in a racing sim (eg: car #, speed, RPM, etc), and the $L messages indicate whenever a car pits out (PO - enters the track), pits in (PI - leaves the track), or crosses the start/finish line (SF). I want to group the $P messages from the cars together in "stints" which is defined as the laps (SF) in between the PI & PO messages for that car. For example if car 8 pits out ($L,8,PO), completes 5 laps, then pits in ($L,8,PI), I want to write a file containing the $P data for those laps (repeat for each car on track and each stint the cars have).

Comment: This is now partially working. I see the output grouped by lap number, but my output files will need to be for each stint (laps between PO & PI). For example, in my initial log file example, If I add additional PI, PO, and SF lines and have a $P for car #8 in between the PO & PI, I get lap 3 for $P with no indication that it is part of a new stint.

Comment: Thanks for this, the ordering is great. However, I don't think I properly explained what I meant by stint. Please see [this annotated](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/VKg67jFrG6/) input and output for what I had meant by my above comment.

Comment: Is code working?  I see the posting for 4/5/21 got deleted.

Comment: This code works (I had flagged it as the answer), but the project scope expanded and I needed to add an additional calculation. I deleted the newer posting because my question was not well worded and I'm going to reexamine my options.